# gcloud app deploy giving internal 500 error

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

We have a pythong/django/glcoud mysql db and a working website. A coworker managed the entire site left the company and now when we try to deploy small changes either it errors out "too many files" or we remove the venv folders and get an internal 500 server error on production which we migrate back our changes to before the latest deployment.

Comment: Please include the deployables (e.g. `app.yaml`) and logs. You should be able to retain traffic on the working version while you debug the issues that are causing the errors from recent deployments.

Comment: Where do I find the logs?

Comment: [`gcloud app logs tail`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/tail)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: app.yml: runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT xpotools.wsgi

#Determines the type of cpu instance it has
instance_class : F4_1G

automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 5
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: 4s
  max_concurrent_requests: 20
  min_idle_instances: 3

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always

- url: /_ah/warmup
  script: auto